# what is a good library or plugin to render json data into html ?

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery, render

I'm making an ajax call to fetch json data. What I get is something like this:

```
{
    "footerPkg": [
        {
            "hotelRoomPrice": 100,
            "idHolidayPackage": 1,
            "OriginCity": "New York",
            "itineraryHeader": "Trip to New York",
            "name": "Holiday Package 1"
        },
        {
            "hotelRoomPrice": 50,
            "idHolidayPackage": 1,
            "OriginCity": "Los Angeles",
            "itineraryHeader": "Amazing Los Angeles",
            "name": "Holiday Package 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to display this json array data like this:

[image: Package]

Is there a **templating engine** or some other technique where I can specify the css and other html styling on the json parameters like I would apply on other html elements ?

Something like this would be great:

(assuming fragment-1 is the id for each element in the array )

```
data = array[0];
    <div id="fragment-1">
             <table><tr>
            <td><img src='data.image.path' alt="${data.image.altText}" title="${data.image.title}">
            <div id="overlaytextlistinglayout">
            <b><a>data.itineraryHeader</a></b><br>
            <br><a style="color: #000000 ">data.name</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: @JonFriskics Mustache is awesome. got it to work fairly quickly! Thanks. I wish I could mark your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), and its been so far so good!

PS: Wanted to mark @Jon Friskics comment as the answer, but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a good one for you: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx

Comment: I looked into this, but jquery has decided not to include templates past Beta :( http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Comment: I didn't realize that about templates but I found this : http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html